# What step in the Next.js webpack compiler adds @layer to the CSS, and how can we stop this?

Tags: css, webpack, next.js

I'm using Next.js with the App Router. I'm importing a few global CSS packages in my `app/layout.js` file:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "primereact/resources/themes/mdc-light-indigo/theme.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
import "./primereact-override.css";
import "./globals.css";
```

This is the order I want to import them in (e.g. I want PrimeReact to override Bootstrap's classes). Next.js seems to be respecting this order in the final compiled CSS file.

However, in the final compiled CSS file (tested in dev mode), `@layer primereact { ... }` is getting added to most of the PrimeReact classes, which is making Bootstrap's classes take priority over them. There is no `@layer` in the original `primereact/resources/themes/mdc-light-indigo/theme.css` file. 1) Why is this happening? 2) How to stop it and achieve the desired behaviour?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue with Next.js - PrimeReact added these layers recently. See https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/5124